# Why do we only need a double integral to compute the centre of mass in this problem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I am confused with the following;

Asked to find the centre of mass of the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$ above the plane $z=4$.

In the solutions, it uses that $$M=\iint_{S} \delta dS$$ where \delta is constant.

But I am confused, I thought when calculating centre of mass in three dimension we use the triple integral over the volume

Can someone please help to explain this to me why they are equivalent?

Comment: A little more detail, if you please.  Where is $S$?  Is the sphere solid ball or hollow sphere? (And does it have a density function?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a triple integral, indeed, when the solid is 3-dimensional.

But here, you are dealing with a surface, which is a 2-dimensional solid (in a 3-dimensional space).

Perhaps you misunderstood the difference between a sphere and a ball.

Comment: Thanks but how do I know that I only have to evaluate the surface

Comment: oh. is it because it is just a sphere not a ball?

Comment: Yes,   that's exactly it!